# Polymorphism Requires Allocation

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

Using polymorphism in C++ usually requires dynamic allocation, use of the factory pattern, etc. Is that not a true statement? Sure, I can instantiate a derived type on the stack if I really try, but is that every day code or an academic exercise?

Some other object orientated languages allocate every user made type on the heap. However, any allocation in C++ us likely to raise debates over performance with your peers.

How then, are you to use polymorphism while keeping allocation to a minimum?

Also, are we really writing real world code while using polymorphism without any dynamic allocation? Are we to forget we ever learned the factory pattern?

---

Edit:

It seems to me in this Q&A that we have identified a difference between scenarios where the type is known at compile time or it isn't.

It has been brought up that the use of streams are an example of polymorphism without dynamic allocation. However, when you are using streams, you know the type you need as you are typing out your program.

On the other hand, there are the scenarios where you don't know the type at compile time. This is where I reach (and have been taught to reach) for the factory pattern. Given some input, decide what concrete type to instantiate. I don't see any alternative to this. Is there one?

--

Let's try to use a scenario that came up in real world code.

Let us assume a stock trading system.
Your job is to store orders that arrive over the network from customers.

- Your input is JSON text.
- Your output should be a collection of data structures representing the orders
- An order could be a vanilla stock purchase, an Option, or a Future.
- You do not know what customers are ordering until you parse the JSON

Naturally, I'd come up with something like this, super simplified for purposes of example, domain:

```
class Order
{
protected:
    double   m_price;
    unsigned m_size;
};

class Option : public Order
{
protected:
    string m_expirationDate;
};

class Future : public Order
{
protected:
    string m_expirationDate;
};
```

And then I'd come up with some factory that parses the JSON and spits out an order:

```
class OrderFactory
{
    Order * CreateOrder(const std::string & json);
};
```

The factory allocates. Therefore, your peers are likely to point out that it's slow in a system that receives millions of orders per second.

I suppose we could convert our domain to some C like monstrosity:

```
struct Order
{
    enum OrderType
    {
         ORDER_TYPE_VANILLA,
         ORDER_TYPE_OPTION,
         ORDER_TYPE_FUTURE
    }

    OrderType   m_type;
    double      m_price;
    unsigned    m_size;
    std::string m_expirationDate;  // empty means it isnt used
    int         m_callOrPut        // Encoder rings are great for code!
                                   // -1  - not used
                                   //  0  - Put
                                   //  1  - Call
};
```

but then we are just ditching polymorphism, and what I think are good OO principles, altogether. We'd still, most likely be allocating these and storing them as they came in too. Unless we want to declare some statically sized container for them and mark elements used or un-used....(yet more C)

Is there some alternative that would not allocate that I am not aware of?

Comment: As you can have polymorphism with references instead of pointers, why not showcase it _without_ dynamic allocation? ;-) [YouTube link: Kate Gregory, "Stop teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) @ CppCon 2015

Comment: isn't the standard iostream/fstream a good example?

Comment: @DevSolar Like I said, I could, but are we all really expected to program up the use of every inheritance hierarchy using references in production code?

Comment: @phon streams are about the most complicated and hard to use example anyone could use for anything. :P

Comment: If I would answer at length, we would rapidly go down the "this is not a forum" line. I believe deep inheritance hierarchies to be a code smell, because you usually don't need them in the first place. Java needs everything to inherit, because that's how the language works. C++ doesn't...

Comment: @ChristopherPisz - Streams are complicated, but you can use them polymorphically without a single `new fstream`, right?

Comment: @DevSolar Feel free to PM me any discussion. I am highly interested in this.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. This is Q&A site, not rant-and-vent site.

Comment: @sergey Re-Read: "how are you to use polymorphism while keeping allocation to a minimum?"

Comment: @ChristopherPisz than I suggest you rephrase the question, removing all rant about interviewers and other languages, and the rest and ask a plain question exactly as in your comment, maybe with couple of additional words that you want to do it for performance benefits. The question as it stands is on direct path to closure and downvote to oblivion.

Comment: @Sergey Edited the OP

Comment: My career began working in Haskell, where "polymorphism" refers to something much closer to C++ templates.  Now that I write C++ professionally, I only rarely need runtime polymorphism, and only with things such as streams or `std::function`.

Comment: Stock trading system can't trade options, equity is another word for stock.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, rather than argue over terminology which is irrelevant to the question, I edited the OP to use the word "vanilla."

Answer (score 3):

> Using polymorphism in C++ usually requires dynamic allocation, use of
>   the factory pattern, etc. Is that not a true statement? Sure, I can
>   instantiate a derived type on the stack if I really try, but is that
>   every day code or an academic exercise?

"Usually" is a bit meaningless; it's a fuzzy comparison on which there are no metrics to produce statistics.  Is it possible to use polymorphism without dynamic allocation?  Yes, trivially.  Consider this case:

```
struct A{};
struct B : A;
void foo(A& a) {};
void foo(A* a) {};
void bar() {
    B b;
    foo(b);
    foo(&b);
}
```

and no dynamic memory used.

Comment: So, in real world code, all you have to do is no that all which concrete type of order all of your customers are going to make while you are writing your program? I dunno if that's a good example. Let me think for a minute and try to come up with a real world scenario where this discussion applies that would be good for demonstration.

Comment: foo doesn't need to know anything about B - it doesn't need to know it exists.    Why do you think that means it needs to know the concrete types?  (Note that A could be concrete too!)

Comment: UKMonkey bar knows we need a B.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz yes - but foo doesn't; and SOMETHING needs to know the top type to be able to create the item ... even with dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes, ....a factory, based on input, typically, which is what I am getting at with the original question. I don't see an alternative when you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: "Yes, ....a factory, based on input, typically"   typically no; factories are sometimes used sure, but you're trying to make generalisations with no data; and then ask a question having already made the assumption about the answer - you can't learn if you have already assumed the answer!  If you're asking "does a factory need to use dynamic memory allocation" the answer is again no, it might be a factory around singletons.  I think you need to stop and re-think about what you really want to ask.

Comment: ok, edited the OP to contain a specific scenario. Can you present an example that meets the requirements without allocation? That's what I am after. What is the alternative, which I'd like to learn, to using dynamic allocation for a polymorphic type, when the type is only known at run time? In this example, the type is known at compile time.

Comment: After your edits - it looks like you're trying to do premature optimisation.  Yes, allocation is "slow" but I'd put good money that your database access is slower.  By an order of magnitude.  Or 2.  But to answer your question, what you want is an object pool - which will return smart pointers (not raw) to objects which the pool can then reused.

Comment: The database argument is the same one I am presenting to my peers. Yes, I think the entire argument is premature optimization as well, but the argument comes up again and again everywhere I go, so I might as well get to the bottom of it. When you say object pool, do you mean a preallocated pool using placement new or some such? I think I can see that.

Answer (score 1):

First off, in C++ people often distinguish compile-time and run-time polymorphis, I take it, your question is about run-time polymorphic behavior.

Yes, there are ways to enjoy polymorphism without using dynamic allocation. A good example of such are streams in STL. (Although, a lot of people question their design, but that's beside the point).

There are people who say that unless you have a container of (pointers to) polymorphic objects of different dynamic types, run-time polymorphism is really not needed and templates would work better - but since templates comes at their own cost, sometimes run-time polymorphism is suited better.

Comment: I believe I am after the scenario where the criteria is met for :" unless you have a container of (pointers to) polymorphic objects of different dynamic types."

Is it your belief that, in that scenario, dynamic allocation, is indeed required?